# Dynamically save & add new input field to bottom of form when submit button is pressed | JADE / NODE JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, postgresql, pug

I have an interesting one to approach today and was hoping you might be able to shed some light on how to approach this task!

I'm trying to build a form that will feature three main elements;

- list title
- List description
- List contents []

See below for how I have my form currently rendered (Just simple bootstrap / Jade)

[image: Current view]

The seemingly difficult part is how to display the content array for users be able to add / edit entries.

What I want is for each entry in the content array to be displayed as an

```
<input type="text">
```

element and have the value pre-filled depending on what was saved in the array (database side).

I was thinking something along the lines of (forgive sudo code):

```
// postgres database extraction
pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client, done) {
    if(err) {
        return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);
    }
    var query = client.query('SELECT title, description, content FROM lists WHERE listid = id');

    query.on('row', function(row) {
        done();
        if(err) {
            return console.error('error fetching client list from pool', err);
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
    });
});
// Where content is an array with each line representing an entry, I'm still not sure how to extract this to an array

var contentList = row[2][];

// Begin JADE template

form.form-horizontal(method='post', role='form')
    input(name='_csrf', type='hidden', value=csrfToken)

    //(*title and description inputs here*)
    // Iterates through each element in the content 
    contentList.forEach(function(entry) {

        label.col-sm-4 Short Description
            div.col-sm-8
                input.form-control(
                    placeholder='New list line',
                    required=true,
                    name='listDescription',
                    type='text',
                    value=contentList[entry])
    });
```

I want to get it so that when a user types into the bottom input box, that content is added to the content list array, and a new input box is dynamically generated below it. (neverending form).

[image: How I want it to function]

Just as when new input boxes are edited they are saved, I want users to be able to click on any input box, see a + appear to the right of it, and they can save content in a similar manner.

This functionality is quite ambitious for my abilities (new to node / js), so I thought best to ask here for directional advice before I waste countless hours making mistakes. Any help appreciated!

Edit: spelling.

Comment: you should give a simpler example, but it seems that it's a javascript question, not jade. Or do you want to render jade templates on the client?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, perhaps I'll rewrite it this afternoon.

I do want to render jade templates on the client, but I don't know how to dynamically add extra inputs boxes on submission.

Comment: I assume that you're doing a XHR when the user clicks on save. So you need to handle the request of the XHR and for this you need JavaScript. In the response handler you just need to render the template and append it to the end of your form.